# Why can't apache block visitors by IP address?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-1.3

I have the following code in my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost 198.71.60.211:80>
     ServerAdmin something@site.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /var/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/mysite.com>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 97.107.131.11
</Directory>
```

Then i restarted apache.  But for some reason, everyone can still see the website.  I want only users with IP address 97.107.131.11 to be able to see my site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you testing? What URL are you using?

Comment: I tested by going to the actual url `http://mysite[dot]com` .  I can't disclose the url right now.  But when i tell my friends to go to it, they can see the site .   I remember the code above worked before on another CentOS server.  But it doesn't seem to be working on this ubuntu server. Am I missing modules for apache or something?

Comment: I don't really follow.  In the DNS settings for mysite.com, i made an A record with the ip address 198.71.60.211, because that's the IP address of my ubuntu/apache server.  Then I'm expecting anyone with an authorized IP address to be able to type http://mysite[dot]com into their browser and see the pages served from the /var/www/mysite.com/public_html folder. The only issue is that Apache isn't denying non-97.107.131.11 ip address users.  Everyone is seeing the contents of /var/www/mysite.com/public_html .  Can you tell me what I mis-understood about the set up?

Comment: You're 100% positive the URL contains `/mysite.com/` and not a `www` or anything else in there?

Comment: yeah i don't use the www version.  The www version is actually a different site all together.

Comment: Maybe it's because the `Directory` directive is for a path that's outside of the site's root? That definitely seems like a mistake, but I'm not sure what consequences it would have.

Comment: Please share your complete config, a <Location /> block with Allow from all could thwart this.

Comment: @fuero that is my complete vhost file aside from another default vhost that comes with apache.  What is this Location block you speak of?  I've never used it before

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711716/apache-restrict-access-to-specific-source-ip-inside-virtual-host

Ensure you are loading mod_authz_host

Answer (score 0):

Double check your DNS lookup for your "mysite.com" from your friend's computers - they could be connecting through a different interface to the service with the same DocumentRoot, or a page which looks the same as what you're trying to protect.